# R shiny conditional input using uioutput

Tags: r, shiny

I was trying to R shiny page for the conditional input where each input depends on the condition of previous input and I am getting some warning. I appreciate for any help.

Here is my code-

Input "leaf_texture" is independent but after that "crop_heightout" is conditional on "leaf_texture". input "field_greenhouseout" is conditional on "crop_heightout" and so on.

```
library(shiny) 
library(shinydashboard)
library(flexdashboard)
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinythemes)


# Define UI
ui <- dashboardPage(
    
    dashboardHeader(title="ABC model", titleWidth = 400
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
      
      sidebarMenu(id = "sidebarmenu",
                  menuItem("Predictive Model", tabName = "model", icon = icon("chart-line"),
                           menuSubItem("Model_Prediction", tabName = "data3", icon = icon("table"))
                  )     
      )
    ),
    dashboardBody(
      tabItem(tabName = "data3",
              h2("ABC Model Prediction"),
              tabBox(id="t1", width = 12, 
                     tabPanel("RF-Model", 
                              fluidRow(   #Filters for categorical variables
                                box(title = 'ABC Model Input',
                                    status = 'success', solidHeader = TRUE, width = 12,
                                    splitLayout(
                                      tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible;}"))),
                                      cellWidths = c('0%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '8%'),
                                      
                                      radioButtons("leaf_texture", "Leaf Texture", choices = c('Hairy','Smooth','Waxy'), selected = "Hairy"),
                                      
                                      div(),
                                      
                                      uiOutput("crop_heightout"),
                                      
                                      div(),
                                      uiOutput("field_greenhouseout"),

                                      div(),
                                      uiOutput("portfolioout")
                                      
                                    ),
                                    actionButton('cal','Predict', style = "background-color: #008000; color: white; border: none; border-radius: 5px; padding: 10px 20px; font-size: 16px;")
                                ),
                                
                                mainPanel(
                                  tags$head(
                                    tags$style(HTML("/* Custom CSS to add more spacing between rows */
                                      .row-spacing {margin-bottom: 50px;}"))
                                  ),
                                  tags$div(class = "row-spacing"),
                                  fluidRow(
                                      dataTableOutput("predicted_table")
                                  )
                                )
                              )
                     )
              )
      )
      
    )
  )


server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  a <- reactiveValues(result = NULL)
  
  output$crop_heightout <- renderUI({
    print(input$leaf_texture)
    if (input$leaf_texture == 'Hairy') {
      radioButtons("crop_height", "Crop_Height", c('Low Crop'), selected = 'Low Crop')
    }else {
      radioButtons("crop_height", "Crop_Height", c('High Crop', 'Low Crop'), selected = 'High Crop')
    }
  })  
  


  output$field_greenhouseout <- renderUI({
    if (input$crop_height %in% c('High Crop', 'Low Crop')) {
      radioButtons("field_greenhouse", "Field_Greenhouse", c('Field', 'GreenHouse'), selected = 'Field')
    }else{
      radioButtons("field_greenhouse", "Field_Greenhouse", c('Field', 'GreenHouse'), selected = 'Field')
    }
  })

  output$portfolioout <- renderUI({
    if (input$field_greenhouse == 'Field') {
      radioButtons("portfolio", "Portfolio", c('Fungicide', 'Herbicide', 'Insecticide'), selected = 'Fungicide')
    }else if (input$field_greenhouse == 'GreenHouse') {
      radioButtons("portfolio", "Portfolio", c('Fungicide', 'Insecticide'), selected = 'Fungicide')
    }else {
      radioButtons("portfolio", "Portfolio", c('Fungicide', 'Herbicide', 'Insecticide'), selected = 'Fungicide')
    }
  })


  observeEvent(input$cal, {
    # Data frame for the single prediction
    values <- data.frame(
      Indication = input$portfolio,
      LeafTexture = input$leaf_texture,
      CropHeight = input$crop_height,
      FieldGreenhouse = as.character(ifelse(input$field_greenhouse=="Field", "F", "GH"))
    )
    # print(values)
    a$result <<- values
  })
  
  output$predicted_table <- renderDataTable({
    if (!is.null(a$result)) {
      results <- a$result
      print(results)
      # Display the table
      datatable(results, options = list(pageLength = 10))
    }
  })
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Here is the warning

```
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  97: renderUI [C:/App/App V2/ui_part.R#90]
  96: func
  83: renderFunc
  82: output$field_greenhouseout
   1: runApp
Warning: Error in if: argument is of length zero
  97: renderUI [C:/App/App V2/ui_part.R#98]
  96: func
  83: renderFunc
  82: output$portfolioout
   1: runApp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure the values exist before you do conditional checks on them. One easy way is to use the `req()` function. For example

```
  output$field_greenhouseout <- renderUI({
    if (req(input$crop_height) %in% c('High Crop', 'Low Crop')) {
      radioButtons("field_greenhouse", "Field_Greenhouse", c('Field', 'GreenHouse'), selected = 'Field')
    }else{
      radioButtons("field_greenhouse", "Field_Greenhouse", c('Field', 'GreenHouse'), selected = 'Field')
    }
  })
  
  output$portfolioout <- renderUI({
    if (req(input$field_greenhouse) == 'Field') {
      radioButtons("portfolio", "Portfolio", c('Fungicide', 'Herbicide', 'Insecticide'), selected = 'Fungicide')
    }else if (input$field_greenhouse == 'GreenHouse') {
      radioButtons("portfolio", "Portfolio", c('Fungicide', 'Insecticide'), selected = 'Fungicide')
    }else {
      radioButtons("portfolio", "Portfolio", c('Fungicide', 'Herbicide', 'Insecticide'), selected = 'Fungicide')
    }
  })
```

Note how `input$crop_height` was changed to `req(input$crop_height)` and so on. That will prevent the error about the if condition being length 0.